# controlling the names of the generated files

Tags: tex4ht

If my `.tex` file is named `book.tex`, the files tex4ht generates are named like this:

- parts: `bookpa[number of part].html`
- chapters: `bookch[number of chapter].html`
- similarly for sections etc
- pictorial math: `book0x.png`, `book1x.png`, `book2x.png`, ...
- similarly if I change the image format to `svg`

Is there a way to change these naming patterns? More specifically:

- Can you change the default name of chapters to be `chapter[number of chapter].html` or even `[name of chapter].html` with the name of the chapter as specified in the corresponding `\chapter{}` command in the `.tex` source file?
- Instead of the consecutive numbering in the names of the images, is it possible to use the number of the corresponding page in the `.idv` file?